# gsub regex method to extract multiple quoted strings in R column

Tags: r, regex

I have DF with strings like this --

```
c(Read1 = "101", Index1 = "0", Index2 = "0", Read2 = "0")
```

I would like to use `gsub()` and regex to extract those integer values within each quote.

Output would be something like,

```
101 0 0 0
```

They can also have a delimiter. I would like to take the sum of each list in the row for my final output.

I have a crappy method in R that extracts it all but doesn't insert a delimiter or space, and wanted to ask for help in doing that. Or just a better method if anyone has one. :)

Currently using....

```
<- as.data.frame(gsub('.*?"(.*?)".*?+', "\\1", proto_runs$CompletedCycles))
which is outputting....
101000)
```

Comment: You already have the integer values. I do not see the need of `gsub` here, since this is a named vector

Comment: `as.integer(x)` should do it

Comment: @Oyambu not sure what you mean by that. I do have the integer values, but since there is no delimiter, I cannot sum them without error. Values for each index can range from 0-151. I need a better gsub method that allows me to sperate each instance

Comment: Run this: `x <- c(Read1 = "101", Index1 = "0", Index2 = "0", Read2 = "0")` then run `as.integer(x)`

Comment: Is your object a named character vector as @Onyambu's comment uses, or is your object a complete string that looks like an R object, something like `"c(Read1 = \"101\", Index1 = \"0\", Index2 = \"0\", Read2 = \"0\")"`?

Comment: Try `library(stringr)` and then `lapply(str_extract_all(proto_runs$CompletedCycles, '(?<=")\\d+(?=")'), function(z) sum(as.numeric(z)))`

Comment: ChristopherMorrissey, any thoughts? You've been silent despite clear questions to clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean you have character strings like this:

```r
string <- 'c(Read1 = "101", Index1 = "0", Index2 = "0", Read2 = "0")'
```

In which case you can do:

```
gsub("[\",A-z\\(\\)=]|([A-z]\\d)", "", string)
#> [1] "  101   0   0   0"
```

If you want the sum of the numbers, you could have:

```
sapply(strsplit(trimws(gsub("[\",A-z\\(\\)=]|([A-z]\\d)", "", string)), "\\D+"), 
       function(x) sum(as.numeric(x)))
#> [1] 101
```

Though an even easier way that actually returns a vector of numbers would be:

```r
as.numeric(eval(parse(text = string)))
#> [1] 101   0   0   0
```

Comment: FYI: [`[A-z]` matches more than just letters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926#29771926).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks - yes, that can sometimes be problematic if overlooked, but I think in this case it is reasonable, since we want to capture and remove any underscores etc too

Comment: That is fine if it is intended, but since it is a very mischievous pattern that needs a remark when used intentionally.

Answer (score 1):

If this is your data:

```
string <- 'c(Read1 = "101", Index1 = "0", Index2 = "0", Read2 = "0")'
```

you can use `str_extract`and a negative character class:

```
library(stringr)
as.numeric(unlist(str_extract_all(string, '(?<=")[^",]+(?=")')))
[1] 101   0   0   0
```

To take the sum simply wrap the function `sum` around the expression:

```
sum(as.numeric(unlist(str_extract_all (string, '(?<=")[^",]+(?=")'))))
[1] 101
```

Comment: doesnt work on the data frame I described. its a data frame of a bunch of them.

Comment: Well, then post some of your actual data

Answer (score 0):

Now this is interesting: If your string is a correct R syntax, just `parse`  it and `eval`uate

```
string <- 'c(Read1 = "101", Index1 = "0", Index2 = "0", Read2 = "0")'

as.integer(eval(parse(text=string)))
[1] 101   0   0   0
```